# Probability that a determinant is equal to zero.

Tags: probability, determinant

Let $A \in M_{n,n}(\mathbb{R})$.

What is the probability that, when I fill in the entries with random real numbers, $det(A) =0$? This looks like an interesting problem, as having determinant zero is equivalent to a lot of other things. For example, the answer to this question gives us information about the percentage of systems $AX = B$ where $A \in M_{n,n}(\mathbb{R})$ that have a unique solution (Cramer's rule)

And what if:

1)  $A \in M_{n,n}(\mathbb{C})$?

2)  All entries must be natural numbers/integers/rational numbers

Comment: In the case of random real numbers, the probability is $0$. More interesting is to assume that the entries are integers in some given range

Comment: For why the probability must be zero, recall that $\det A = 0\iff$ a column is linearly dependent.  For this to be true for a $n\times n$ matrix, a column must be in the span of the other $n-1$ columns.  This is a $n-1$ dimension subspace, so the measure of it (in the $n$ dimension space) is $0$.

Comment: "Almost never."  In the 2x2 case, it would be the equivalent question as what is the probability that 3 randomly chosen points are on a line.

Comment: @Peter Could you have the answer? I found some solutions for a specific range, but I don't know what the specific probability formula is when the given range is $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even in the simplest case of $n=2$ over $\mathbb{R}$ you are asking what is the probability that $ad = bc$ where $a,b,c,d$ are random. This is clearly 0.

All others can be argued similarly. To make this interesting, ensure you are sampling entries from a finite distribution.

Comment: I did not take a probability theory course yet, but I think it's weird that the probability is actually zero, as there are cases where the determinant is zero. Is this the result from a limiting proces? Something like (stupid example): the probability is 1/n with n very large, thus equals zero?

Comment: "There are cases where the determinant is zero" this is because the systems you are considering are not truly random from over all reals. Imposed structure implies non-zero probabilities. The issue is somewhat intuitively similar to what you've described with the 1/n, and n being infinitely large.

Comment: @Math_QED "1/n with n very large" is still not zero. However, the probability of a matrix being singular truly _is_ zero. This is an example that an event is possible even if the probability is zero. Here is a simpler example: pick a random real number from an interval $[0,1]$, say you've picked $\alpha$. I hope you are sufficiently convinced that the event of having (randomly) chosen $\alpha$ is thus possible. But if you were to find the probability of this happening, for this single fixed $\alpha$, you'd easily find the probability is zero.

Comment: There is a phrase in probability theory "almost surely" and "almost never" that cover events that happen with probability 1, 0, respectively.  An example would be the probability that a dart hits a specific point on your black board when thrown.  There are infinitely many points it could hit, and only 1 that meets the criteria.  This is an event that happens "almost never."

Comment: @Math_QED Yes, probability on reals is weird! If you just "draw" a random real between 0 and 1, then $P(X=1/2)=0$. Heck, this is actually true for *any* $x$ --- $P(X=x)=0$. In probability, "zero probability" is not the same as "impossible".

Answer (score 1):

For part $2)$ - Firstly note that the determinant of a 'rational' matrix $A$ is $0$ if and only if the determinant of the matrix $\lambda A$ is $0$, where $\lambda$ is the product of all the denominators of the entries of $A$. Clearly $\lambda A$ has integer entries. Therefore if we can show that the probability of picking a matrix with integer coefficients that has determinant $0$ is $0$, then the same holds for rational matrices.

By symmetry, given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the probability that a randomly selected integer matrix has determinant equivalent to $0$ modulo $n$ is $1/n$. The probability that a random integer matrix has determinant $0$ is less than this. Hence the probability is less than $1/n$. Since this holds for all $n$, letting $n$ tend to infinity shows that this probability is $0$. Hope this helps.